# import data from JSON in solr

Tags: json, solr

Currently I am using XML file in solr.
I index xml file's data using DataimportHandler with XPathentityProcessor.

Now I want to import data from json file.

Is there any example ?

Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 9):

What you need is something like

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' --data-binary @books.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Taken from the example.

Source: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON

Comment: in above url, how to use that json file? I mean how to provide path of that json file. and can we use it by URLDatasource?

Comment: I want to do request from url, dont want to use curl.
is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: @SagarJoshi you mean like submitting a form with data as json to solr?

Comment: :: what exactly i want is, I have json file, i want to index it.

and the url that you mentioned above , it gives curl parameter, Is it possible to use it in direct url? as a GET or POST request?

Comment: curl speaks HTTP, the url I provided is a HTTP-POST. In the example curl is using HTTP-POST to post the books.json file to solr.

Comment: I used curl that u mentioned above:

It was like this:
curl "http://hostname:8080/solr/core/update/json?commit=true" --data
-binary @test.json -H "Content-type:application/json"

It gives me below xml::

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">59</int><
/lst>
</response>

After this , when I searched by below url::

http://hostname:8080/solr/core/select?q=*:*
I do not get any response.

Is there anything which I am missing to do?

Comment: there shouldn't be a space in '--data -binary'
also can you do a hostname:8080/solr/core/select?q=*:*&debugQuery=true ?

Answer (score 5):

DataImportHandler does not allow you to use JSON as a source. The only way is to use Update Handler which can handle JSON natively. But that has to be in [the JSON structure Solr expects](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) (array of hashes or hash of command/hashes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have seen that url that you have provided.
But in that it using curl.I do not want to use any command prompt.
So is it possible to get data from json file directly from url only? or anything such like that?

Comment: But is your URL in the form Solr can parse (link above). If not, you are stuck. If it is, you could look at using [stream.URL](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ContentStream)

Comment: Link has moved to: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-JSONFormattedIndexUpdates

Answer (score 3):

if you dont want to use curl command, you can fire the command directly on the browser and get the desired result:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true --data-binary @books.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'`

Put the json file in /example/exampledocs folder.This is default directory path in solr.
If you are using java or php etc then there are several classes and methods that you use and then you wont require to mention the entire command as above.Is that what you were asking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can also update your docs by including the ?commit=true statement within the url of a curl command like so.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "{usernamne}":"{password}" "https://your_host/solr/your_collection/update/json?commit=true" --data-binary @/path/to/your/data/your_data.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want import part or the entire collection from a json format, well, there is an alternative.

I wrote a java tool: https://github.com/freedev/solr-import-export-json

This is a java application that imports and exports a Solr collection using `SolrJ`. Every document has to be a json object and in the file you are importing you must have a list of lines whereas each line is a json object.

```
{ "id": 1, "date": "20160101T00:00:00", "text": "some text" } 
{ "id": 2, "date": "20160102T00:00:00", "text": "some text" } 
{ "id": 3, "date": "20160103T00:00:00", "text": "some text" }
```

I haven't tried with nested documents, and the keys of json document should be exactly the names of the Solr fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST api to send data to Solr. Please use this path:

```
localhost:8983/solr/simple2/update?commit=true
//(simple2 is the core name and localhost:8983 is server path.)
```

and you have to define

```
:content_type => 'application/json'
```

in request header.Along with it you can send json file/data to solr using post request.

For more information you can visit http://geekdirt.com/blog/indexing-in-solr-using-json-and-rest-apis/